# generation uncorrelated random sequence

Tags: matlab

I want to generate an uncorrelated stochastic random sequence with zero mean and unit variance to use it as input.and also I need to generate a white noise sequence with zero mean and variance 4.how can I do it?

Comment: Try looking at `randn`

Answer (score 1):

You can find some random generator at https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/random-number-generation.html.

If you are looking for a uniformly distributed random numbers, you can use **rand** and for a normally distributed random numbers **randn**. If you will use **randn**, you could change the mean and variance by using ***(randn * variance) + mean***